# How to select rows which are mapped to a single record in a one to many relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e95e2c/1

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Pants',
    sizes: [
      { size: 'S', price: 1990 },
      { size: 'XL', price 2490 }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id integer primary key,
    name text
);

CREATE TABLE product_size (
    id integer primary key,
    product_id integer,
    size text,
    price integer
);

INSERT INTO product(id, name) VALUES 
(1, 'Pants'), (2, 'Hats');

INSERT INTO product_size(id, product_id, size, price) VALUES 
(1, 1, 'S', 1990), (2, 1, 'XL', 2490), (3, 2, 'S', 990);
    
   
select pr.id, pr."name", count(ps.id) from product pr 
inner join product_size ps on pr.id = ps.product_id 
group by pr.id, pr."name"
having count(ps.id) = 1
```

Result:
|id | name | count |
|---|------|-------|
| 2 | Hats |     1 |